# How to mock the external library graphql-request call using jest

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, jestjs, graphql

I'm encountering difficulties while writing Jest unit tests for a module that interacts with `graphql-request`.

Here's the test

```
import { jest } from '@jest/globals';
import { request } from 'graphql-request';
import {
  logActivityPhoneCallScheduled,
} from './candidateService';

jest.mock('graphql-request', () => {
  return {
    request: jest.fn(),
  };
});

beforeEach(() => {
  jest.clearAllMocks();
});

test('scheduled', async () => {
  request.mockResolvedValue({ addCandidateActivity: { id: 835 } });

  const now = Date.now();
  const input = {
    candidateId: 'TBX-001',
    eventId: 305,
    userId: 'y29d13lkcas91',
    userIsStaff: true,
    scheduledFor: new Date(now + 14 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1e3).toISOString(),
    createdAt: new Date(now - 905 * 1e3).toISOString(),
  };

  const expectedActivity = {
    candidateId: 'TBX-001',
    type: 'SCHEDULE',
    action: 'scheduled',
    newValue: '305',
    additionalPayload: {
      type: 'phonecall',
      scheduled_at: input.scheduledFor,
    },
    userId: 'y29d13lkcas91',
    userIsStaff: true,
    createdAt: input.createdAt,
  };

  const result = await logActivityPhoneCallScheduled(input);

  expect(result).toBe(835);
  expect(request).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
  expect(request.mock.calls[0][0]).toBe('http://candidate-service:5000');
  expect(request.mock.calls[0][1]).toContain('addCandidateActivity');
  expect(request.mock.calls[0][2]).toEqual({ activity: expectedActivity });
});
```

Despite my efforts, I keep encountering errors like

```
TypeError: request.mockResolvedValue is not a function

      18 |
      19 | test('scheduled', async () => {
    > 20 |   request.mockResolvedValue({ addCandidateActivity: { id: 835 } });
         |           ^
      21 |
      22 |   const now = Date.now();
      23 |   const input = {
```

I suspect the issue lies in how I'm trying to mock the `graphql-request` module and its request function.

Could someone please guide me on the correct approach to mock requests made using graphql-request for local testing within Jest? What might be causing the errors I'm facing, and how can I resolve them?

Answer (score 0):

After some investigation and experimentation, I found a solution that effectively mocks the request function and allows for proper unit testing of my GraphQL-related code.

I'd like to share this solution to help others who might encounter similar issues.

In the end, I was able to make use of this online documentation

[jest-esm-almost-there](https://www.sitepen.com/blog/jest-esm-almost-there)

The solution

1. **Mocking the graphql-request Module:**

I used jest.unstable_mockModule to mock the entire graphql-request module. This enabled me to control the behavior of the request function within my tests.

```js
import { jest } from '@jest/globals';

const mockedRequest = jest.fn();
jest.unstable_mockModule('graphql-request', async function mock() {
  return {
    request: (...args) => mockedRequest(...args),
  };
});
```

2. **Importing Service Functions Dynamically:**

I utilized await import() to dynamically import the specific service functions I needed for testing. This approach ensured that I was working with the latest mocked version of the request function.

```js
const { logActivityPhoneCallScheduled } = await import('./candidateService');
```

3. **Setting Up and Running Tests:**

With the mock in place, I set up my test cases as usual. For example:

```js
afterEach(() => {
  jest.resetAllMocks();
});

test('scheduled', async () => {
  mockedRequest.mockResolvedValue({ addCandidateActivity: { id: 835 } });

  // Rest of the test code...
});
```

By using this approach, I was able to successfully mock the behavior of the request function and properly test my GraphQL-related code. This solution provides a clear separation of concerns, making it easier to isolate the behavior of the request function and focus on testing the logic within my service functions.

I hope this solution helps others facing similar issues when testing GraphQL-related code with the graphql-request library. If you're struggling with similar challenges, give this approach a try and adapt it to your specific use case.